# Is there a way to create aliases for only certain directories?

Tags: git, macos, unix

I'm looking for a way to assign an alias that only operates in a single folder, and is easily transferable via git.

I'm imagining some sort of `.aliases` file where I can create things like `ALIAS test=pytest[....]` that will be picked up by others when they pull from this repo.

Is such a thing possibly natively in OSX terminal, or would I need some sort of third party library/manual editing of everybody's `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`?

Thanks for the help, and if anything is unclear please let me know!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52997/how-to-set-an-alias-on-a-per-directory-basis

Comment: helpful -- thanks @miqdadamirali. But I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with only a single file in each directory, without any `~/.bashrc` massaging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible natively. This is mainly for security reasons – you wouldn’t want to download a project, `cd` into its directory, and have it overwrite the `ls` command so that `ls` uploads all your files to a hacker.

There is a tool [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/) for Mac and Linux that automatically loads environment variables from a `.envrc` file when you `cd` into a directory, which is close to what you want, but `direnv` [doesn’t support defining aliases/functions](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/73). (And it requires `direnv` to be installed first.)

Here are some alternatives to aliases for making the same command run different things in different project directories. Which one you should choose depends on the conventions of your project and its ecosystem.

### Shell scripts

A solution that works with many programming languages, but only on Unix, would be to include shell scripts:

`test`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pytest ...
```

And tell people to run it with `./test`.

You could also put all your scripts in a folder such as `script` and tell people to run `script/test`.

### A `Makefile`

If you require [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) to be installed, you could make your scripts cross-platform (which would require avoiding platform-specific commands in your scripts). You would define a `Makefile` containing your aliases:

`Makefile`

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    pytest ...
```

And tell people to run it with `make test`.

### Language-specific scripts, e.g. `package.json` for JavaScript

Some languages have other conventions. For example, if you are using JavaScript with the NPM package manager, the convention is to put scripts in your [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json):

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "my-js-project",
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node tests.js"
  },
}
```

Then people would try the standard command `npm test` and it would call this script. If the script had a non-standard name, you could tell them to `npm run test` instead.

Comment: Wow, incredible answer. Thanks so much for taking the time to help!